# Set bootstrap progress bar property with value from knockout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have the following view model

```
public class CoreSkillsViewModel
{
    public int CoreSkillsId { get; set; }
    public string SkillName { get; set; }
    public double Competency { get; set; }
    public bool IsCoreSkill { get; set; }
}
```

which is returned to my Index.cshtml page by way of an ajax call....

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var employeeId = @ViewBag.UserInfo.UserId;

            function CoreSkillsViewModel() {
                var self = this;

                // Core Skill
                self.CoreSkillsId = ko.observable("");
                self.SkillName = ko.observable("");
                self.Competency = ko.observable("");
                self.IsCoreSkill = ko.observable("");

                var CoreSkill = {
                    CoreSkillsId: self.CoreSkillsId,
                    SkillName: self.SkillName,
                    Competency: self.Competency,
                    IsCoreSkill: self.IsCoreSkill
                };

                self.CoreSkill = ko.observable();
                self.CoreSkillsArray = ko.observableArray();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetSkills", "CoreSkills")',
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: ko.toJSON({ 'UserId' : employeeId }),
                    success: function (data) {
                        self.CoreSkillsArray(data); // Put the response in ObservableArray
                        console.log(ko.toJSON(self.CoreSkillsArray));
                    }
                });

            }

            var viewModel = new CoreSkillsViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });
```

I can see the following data returned in the console: [{"CoreSkillsId":1,"SkillName":"Test Skill 1","Competency":22.65,"IsCoreSkill":true}]

I am using knockout and I have a foreach loop....

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: CoreSkillsArray">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: CoreSkillsId, visible: false" />
      <span data-bind="text: SkillName"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="progress " style="height: 20px;">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="16.67" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 16.67%;">
      <span style="color: #000;">16.67 %</span>
      </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Right now I have the value 16.67 hard-coded in the aria-valuenow, width and text properties.  This is displaying properly but I would like this to be dynamic and the value from the model put in place but I can't bind directly to these properties.

Any idea how to do this?

FOR EXAMPLE: aria-valuenow="data-bind='text: Competency'"

Comment: Have you tried data-bind="attr: { 'aria-valuenow': Competency }"? See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html

Comment: @JasonSpake, I tried the following --> data-bind="style: { width: Competency }, text: Competency, attr: { 'aria-valuenow': Competency }"  This works EXCEPT the width attribute is not being populated....

Comment: This syntax SOLVED the problem: data-bind="style: { color: '#000;', width: Competency + '%' }, attr: { 'aria-valuenow': Competency }"